# Undefined reference to custom shared library

Tags: c, linux, gcc, shared-libraries

I create a `.so` file with the code below, but when I compile a file that invokes functions in the `.so` file with GCC, I get an "undefined reference to 'outlib1'" error.

What's wrong with my code or my command? Thanks.

OS Ubuntu 11.10
gcc 4.6.1

```
//file name outscreen.c

#include <stdio.h>

void outlib1(void)
{
    printf("out screen func1\n");
}
//file name main.c
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    outlib1();
}
```

```
gcc outscreen.c -fPIC -shared -o outscreen.so   
gcc main.c -L. -loutscreen -o call   
./call
```

Comment: How about asking this on the dedicated StackExchange site http://askubuntu.com/ ?

Comment: @nulltoken It’s not an Ubuntu question. It’s a linking question.

Comment: @nulltoken: no, this is on-topic here, not there.

Comment: Have you created a header file with declaration of your function? Such a file must be included into your `main.c`.

Comment: @Mat Ok. However, askubuntu states "We welcome questions about development on Ubuntu.". ;)

Comment: @nulltoken: this is unrelated to Ubuntu.

Comment: yes, i have edited a header file declared the outlib1() function and included it in the main file. @ghik

Comment: This does not even compile as written.  "-loutscreen" pulls in a SO named "liboutscreen.so", but your compile command generated a SO named "outscreen.so".

Comment: gcc -c outscreen.c                                                   gcc -shared -fPIC -o libmyscreen.so outscreen.o
gcc -o call main.c -L. -lmyscreen
I compiled files like this and it's ok.

Comment: @jerrysea you should fix your description in this case, because it's misleading - the fact that you compile to object file first and then link is important. -fPIC should be used when compiling (gcc -c), not when linking the object files into shared library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
$ gcc outscreen.c -fPIC -shared -o liboutscreen.so   
$ gcc main.c -L. -loutscreen -o call
```

(note the change to the first line - the second line is unchanged)

Comment: @jerrysea: see edited answer above - you need to change your first build command but *not* the second

Answer (score 1):

What is the output of this?

```
 nm outscreen.so | grep outlib1
```

Perhaps it is exporting with an underscore.